# Integral with binomial coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients

Is it possible to evaluate this integral without using the gamma function
$$ \int_0^1 {a \choose b}x^b(1-x)^{a-b} dx$$
It looks a little like part of binomial theorem, but I don't have an idea how to manage with that. The solution should be $\frac{b}{a+1}$.

Comment: Binomial is a constant here, anyway, agreed?

Comment: Would you accept a Beta function ?

Comment: @MattAllegro Of course it is a constant

Comment: Just as a sanity check, if you plug in $b=0$ and $a=whatever$, the value $\frac{b}{a+1}$ doesn't make sense for this integral. We can also show by symmetry that the values of the integral for $b$ and $b'=a-b$ should be equal, which doesn't hold for $\frac{b}{a+1}$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $$I(a,b) = \binom{a}{b} \int_{x=0}^1 x^b (1-x)^{a-b} \, dx.$$ Integration by parts approach, with the choice $u = x^b$, $du = bx^{b-1}$, $dv = (1-x)^{a-b} \, dv$, $\displaystyle v = -\frac{(1-x)^{a-b+1}}{a-b+1}$, gives $$\begin{align*} I(a,b) &= \binom{a}{b} \left( \biggl[ -x^b \frac{(1-x)^{a-b+1}}{a-b+1} \biggr]_{x=0}^1 + \frac{b}{a-b+1} \int_{x=0}^1 x^{b-1} (1-x)^{a-b+1} \, dx \right) \\ &= \binom{a}{b}\frac{b}{a-b+1} \binom{a}{b-1}^{-1} I(a,b-1) \\ &= I(a,b-1). \end{align*}$$  By recursion, if $b$ is a positive integer, we then have $$I(a,b) = I(a,0) = \frac{1}{a+1}$$ by direct computation.  More sophisticated methods of evaluation can show that this result holds true as long as $-1 < b < a+1$ and $a \ne -1$ but since you do not want a treatment with the gamma function, it is a bit tedious to speak of the meaning of binomial coefficients of non-integer values.

Comment: Could you please clarify what $\biggl[ -x^b \frac{(1-x)^{a-b+1}}{a-b+1} \biggr]_{x=0}^1$ is doing? In $I(a,b) = uv - \int u'v \;dx$, that fraction comes from $uv$, which is outside any integral. Therefore, I don't see why are you allowed to evaluate that big fraction from $x=0$ to $x=1$ and hence how do you get to the next step.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the generating function $F(y) = \sum_{b=0}^a  y^b \int_0^1 \binom{a}{b} x^b (1-x)^{a-b} \mathrm{d}x$. By the binomial theorem we have

$$F(y) = \int_0^1 (1-(1-y)x)^a \mathrm{d} x = \frac{1}{a+1} \frac{1-y^{a+1}}{1-y} = \frac{1}{a+1}(1+y+\cdots+y^a) $$

Now take the coefficient of $y^b$ to get $\int_0^1 \binom{a}{b} x^b (1-x)^{a-b} \mathrm{d}x = 1/(a+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume $a > b$, and $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$. This is the integral of the kernel of a [Beta density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Probability_density_function) with parameters $\alpha = b+1$ and $\beta = a-b+1$, so use the fact that
\begin{align}
   1
&= \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\int_0^1 x^b (1-x)^{a-b}dx \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\int_0^1 x^b (1-x)^{a-b}dx \\
&= \frac{(a+1)!}{b!(a-b)!}\int_0^1 x^b (1-x)^{a-b}dx \\
&= (a+1)\int_0^1 \binom{a}{b}x^b (1-x)^{a-b}dx \\
\end{align}

**EDIT**

Here is another approach. Write the integral (without the binomial coefficient) as
\begin{align}
   \int_0^1 x^b(1-x)^{a-b}dx
&= \int_0^1 x^b\sum_{i=0}^{a-b} \binom{a-b}{i} (-x)^i dx \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{a-b} \binom{a-b}{i}(-1)^i \int_0^1 x^{b+i} dx \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{a-b} \binom{a-b}{i}(-1)^i \frac{1}{b+i+1} ,
\end{align}
and now multiply both sides by $\binom{a}{b}$. There may be some useful binomial identities to go further, but are you sure about the answer you gave?

Comment: But I still don't see how to get the final form, because without using Beta density I can just take the binomial coefficient before the integral, because it is constant

Comment: @Rop, Well, you can evaluate it by brute force by just doing integration by parts many times over. This is in fact how the recursive relationship of the gamma function is established

Comment: @ I am not sure if you read my post, the question was: if I can and how evaluate this without gamma function